# Given a population, find the boolean algebra expressions that most closely evaluate to that population

Tags: algorithms, logic

### TL;DR

I have some ideas but am curious to know if there are existing proofs, research, etc. in this area that I can use to guide my algorithm development.

### Problem summary

We have a population where each sample has attributes, or tags, associated with it.

The cardinality of the tag set is unbounded, but if it helps, we can constrain it to 50. In practice, there will be a known upper bound.

The number of tags that a sample has must be at least one and has no upper bound, but if it helps, we can constrain that upper bound to 10.

We have an algorithm which can generate a subset of the population by evaluating a [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) expression which uses the set of tags as operands and the `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` operators. In addition, the expression can include parentheses for controlling the order in which sub-expressions are evaluated.

We want to determine an algorithm that can perform the inverse operation...that is to say, given a subset of the population, derive possible boolean algebra expressions which generate it.

### Initial ideas

Getting a result with 100% precision and 100% recall should be theoretically possible if there are no constraints on the complexity of the derived expression.

However, without constraints on the expressions' complexity, the algorithm has an unbounded runtime which I think is unacceptable. Besides, it's desirable to find the best solutions which also factors in simplicity.

Given this constraint, there will likely be a need to choose possible solutions that balance precision and recall given a maximum number of terms.

To me, the obvious starting point is to run some kind of brute force, backtracking algorithm.

### Concerns

I'm not convinced that early stopping with a backtracking algorithm won't prematurely eliminate valid solutions since the addition of new terms can improve results. For example, a potential solution might qualify for elimination because the precision drops below some threshold, but the addition of one more `NOT` operator might vastly improve precision.

I'm also wondering how effective applying some sort of heuristic based on the tags of the given population would be at reducing the search space...

For example, if there is a set of tags that don't appear at all in the population, then those should all be candidate tags to be used with the `NOT` operator. Conversely, any tag that *does* appear in the population should be excluded from use with the `NOT` operator.

---

Does anyone have pointers that could help guide me in solving this problem?

Comment: This can easily become impossible if you attempt to distinguish two elements that have the same tags.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map